# MySQL Benchmarking

Tags: mysql, optimization, benchmarking

I was reading some benchmarking tips and i came across a tip that says "Restart MySQL server to eliminate any unwanted caching factors" from this site: http://blog.monitor.us/2012/09/the-gold-standard-mysql-benchmarking-best-practices/.

However, i read somewhere else a few weeks back (cannot remember from which site) that recommended running MySQL for at least 2-3 days before performing benchmarking to get correct results.

So which is which, restart my SQL before benchmarking, or let it run for a few days before benchmarking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it`s both, IE you want to start fresh so as not to collect any data from sessions before benchmarking started, but in order to collect sufficient data to make benchmarking worthwhile you need to run the server for a decent period.

IE restart the server, start benchmarking, run for 3 days, then look at the results.